# Running hadoop command from Runtime.getRuntime().exec

Tags: java, hadoop, command, runtime.exec

I am using Java8 with CDH5.

I am trying to run *hadoop fs -copyFromLocal* command to copy Java Flight Recorder files captured from each maptask/reducetask to HDFS. I am doing this copy in shutdown hook of a [premain](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html) method.

I cannot use Java API to interact with HDFS because I want to run this via shell script which runs after JVM is killed.

I wrote a script which runs *hadoop* command. Eventually, I want to run *hadoop* command in *nohup* mode to ensure that it runs even after JVM exits.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"/bin/bash", "-c", "./copyFromLocal.sh"});
```

copyFromLocal.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

/usr/bin/hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /localdir/*.jfr /hdfsdir
```

I have tried to run *hadoop* command directly this way but doesn't work:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"/usr/bin/hadoop", "fs -copyFromLocal /localdir/*.jfr /hdfsdir"});

Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"hadoop", "fs -copyFromLocal /localdir/*.jfr /hdfsdir"});
```

I tried to run other *hadoop fs* commands like *-mkdir* or *-ls* but none of them seems to work.

Comment: See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process.  I'd also recommend breaking each part of the command into a separate string of the array.  So instead of `"fs -copyFromLocal /localdir/*.jfr /hdfsdir"` use `"fs", "-copyFromLocal", "/localdir/*.jfr", "/hdfsdir"` ..

Comment: any solution for this?

Comment: @Surbhi Mungre Do you find any solution for this? thx.